# How to display distinct posts from multiple category in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to display all posts under a parent category. The following are the categories:

FAQ (parent categories) 
- Designs (subcategory) 
 
- Arts (subcategory)
 
- Sciences (subcategory)

However, a post contains three subcategories which resulted to duplicate of entries. I want to display **only ONE result** for posts which have assigned to multiple categories. This could be done by prioritizing the primary category.

Example.

inputs:

I love designing  - categories are: Designs, Arts, Sciences

The output is:

I love designing - Designs
I love designing - Arts 
I love designing - Sciences

I expect the result should be : *I love designing - Designs*

The code below displays three rows of posts for  multiple categories.

```
$cats     = get_categories('parent=1');  
foreach ($cats as $cat) 
{
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 20, 
        'post_status'    => 'publish' 
        'category_name'  => $cat->slug
    );
    $category_id   = get_cat_ID($cat->name);
    $category_link = get_category_link( $category_id ); 
    query_posts($args);

    if(have_posts())
    {
        while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
            echo  get_the_title() . ' - '; 
            echo $cat->name;
         endwhile;
    }
 }//foreach
```

Comment: why not just get all the posts from the parents instead of the child categories... and then you don't need to loop on the categories too. I mean you can just do `'category_name'=>'faq'` or whatever your parent category name is..

Comment: thanks man.. I got it now.. :)